# Wait indicator with grayed out JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm looking for some Java library/ class which has two functionalities:

1. I wan't to gray out whole JFrame content during long term operation.
2. Show the wait indicator as a layer on this grayed out JFrame.

I try to find some opensource library, but I couldn't.

I don't want to integrate JavaFX.

Do you know maybe of some good libraries which handle the cover behaviour in a nice way.

Comment: For those that might want this option, a Swing hourglass cursor.  http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I wan't to gray out whole JFrame content during long term operation.
> 2. Show the wait indicator as a layer on this grayed out JFrame.

- use [JLayer(best of ways)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) or [GlassPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#rootpane),
- put there [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) with

  1. animated gif Icon
  2. [few Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) invoked from [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
  3. create an animations (`BufferedImage`) by using `paintComponent` repainted from `Swing Timer`